# Crystal Report not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

**Parameters are not working passing to a crystal reports from vb.net**

**Name Imports Statement**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.Web
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
```

**Code Behind**

```
        Dim rptDocu As New ReportDocument
        Dim crParamFields As New ParameterFields
        Dim crParamField As New ParameterField
        Dim crParamDiscreteVal As ParameterDiscreteValue = Nothing
        Dim crDatabase As Database
        Dim crTables As Tables
        Dim crTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table = Nothing
        Dim crLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo
        Dim crConnInfo As New ConnectionInfo()

        crParamField.ParameterFieldName = "@eno"
        crParamDiscreteVal = New ParameterDiscreteValue
        crParamDiscreteVal.Value = "50269"
        crParamField.CurrentValues.Add(crParamDiscreteVal)
        crParamFields.Add(crParamField)
        CrystalReportViewer2.ParameterFieldInfo = crParamFields

        rptDocu.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport1.rpt"))
        crDatabase = rptDocu.Database
        crTables = crDatabase.Tables
        crTables.Reset()
        CrystalReportViewer2.Dispose()

        For Each crTable In crTables
            With crConnInfo
                .ServerName = "INTRANET"
                .DatabaseName = "Certificate"
                .UserID = "sa"
                .Password = "#######"
            End With

            crLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            crLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnInfo
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crLogOnInfo)
        Next


        For Each cnInfo As TableLogOnInfo In Me.CrystalReportViewer2.LogOnInfo
            cnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnInfo
        Next

        CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = rptDocu
```

**Code Behind**

> No error simply showing blank using parameter